# Spring Security - cannot logout

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, spring-security, logout

I'm beginner of Spring Framework. Me and my friend are writing our engineer thesis on Poznań University of Technology and we have a problem with Spring Security (3.1.0). I can NOT well log out. When I want to log in again I see message "User is already logged in" (I overrode standard Spring Security error message). I was trying to clear context of SecurityContextHolder but It still doesn't work.

spring-security.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" create-session="ifRequired">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/start"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="ROLE_USER" />       
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control 
                max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:form-login login-page="/start"
            default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/login_error?error=true"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/start" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" name="myAuthenticationProvider" class="org.pp.web.Authentication.XtbAuthenticationProvider"/>
</beans>`
```

web.xml

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>



    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

home.jsp

```
<a href="<c:url value="/logout" />">Logout</a>
```

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "logout")
public String logout() {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    return "redirect:/j_spring_security_logout";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "start")
public String start(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // sprawdzenie czy uzytkownik nie jest juz zalogowany
    if (request.getRemoteUser() == null) {

        return "start";
    } else {

        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

I have my own provider to check login and password.

AuthProvider.java

```
public class AuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationProvider.class);

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    String username = String.valueOf(auth.getPrincipal());
    String password = String.valueOf(auth.getCredentials());

    if(username.length()<4)
    {
        logger.warn("Error: Login is to short for username: "+ username);
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Login is to short!");
    }
    else if(password.length()<4)
    {
        logger.warn("Error: Password is to short for username: "+ username);
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Password is to short!");

    }
    else if(!(  (username.equals("login") & password.equals("password"))|
            (username.equals("login2") & password.equals("password2"))) ) {
        logger.warn("Error: Incorrect data for username: "+ username);
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect data!");
    }

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(),
        authorities);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

}

I was trying to fix it and I was looking long time but I can't find solution.

I hope you help me.

Mateusz Jarmuzek,
Lukasz Grzybowski

Edit:
I overrode standard Spring Security error message.

Code after changes.

Controller.java

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "dummy")
public String dummy() {
    //SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    return "redirect:/dummy";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "logout")
public String logout() {
    //SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    return "redirect:/start";
}
```

dummy.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>

<% 

session.invalidate(); 
// String redirectURL = "http://localhost:8080/start";
// response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);

%>

<body>
<%-- <c:redirect url='http://localhost:8080/start' /> --%>
</body>

</html>
```

home.jsp

```
<a href="<c:url value='/dummy' />">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's problem no in JSP redirects but in settings.

Try this:

Add to web.xml

```
<listener> 
<listener-class>
org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard for Spring security log outs is as follows:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

**EDIT**

If you are using jsp redirects, what needs to happen is you need an empty jsp that does the following things:

1)  Invalidates the session
2)  Redirects to a landing page

When I say empty I mean the only content inside of it is a scriptlet that does the two pieces above.  So the process will look as follows:

> 1)  User presses log out
>     2)  A redirect to the dummy page as
>   described above occurs
>    3)  Dummy page executes its code
>     4)  User
>   is now logged out of the system.

**JSP CODE**

```
<html>  
    <%session.invalidate()%>    
    //redirect logic
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't work.

Comment: @user1910842 can you give more details as to how it doesn't work?  Are you using jsp redirects as well?

Comment: Yes, I use redirects. Like in logout() method in Controller.java "return "redirect:/j_spring_security_logout";" If I understand you well.

Comment: @user1910842 updated to explain a workaround

Comment: thanks a lot but I still have problem. Yes, I use JSP redirects. What does it mean to invalidates the session? Is it clearContext() method? I created empty jsp, but I don't know what kind of code executes there.

Comment: @matjar I have posted the scriptlet I was referring to.

Comment: It works but I have HTTP 310 ERROR -> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: @matjar Well perhaps remove the spring security redirect?  I am not sure, it works just fine in my system

Comment: I updated my first post.

Comment: @Woot4Moo The main detail is that it's Spring - and Spring just plain sucks. 100500 ways to do a simple damn logout and none of them work!