# Cannot log out with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've got Spring Security configured to do everything I want except successfully log me out.  When I click my logout link, it either throws a 404 or takes me to the login page without logging me out depending on the specific configuration.  Also of note, if I go to the login page while logged in and type the wrong username or password, I am logged out.  That indicates to me that access denied is working properly.  Please comment if you see a mistake or have advice on how to better implement my solution.  Thanks.

web.xml:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

app-security.xml:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/app/login" default-target-url="/app" authentication-failure-url="/app/login" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/app/login" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="d" password="d" authorities="USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

HomeController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model) {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/app/accessdenied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "denied";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/app/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "logout";
}
```

Logout link in .jsp file:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/logout" method="get">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Security - cannot logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920729/spring-security-cannot-logout)

Comment: Don't use a controller, spring security already logs out. Instead of `/app/logout` use `/j_spring_security_logout` and simple remove yuor controller method.

Answer (score 0):

As @M. Denium pointed out, you can simply point your logout link to `/j_spring_security_logout`.

If you want a "pretty" logout url, you can use the `logout-url` atrribute of the `security:logout` to filter on your `/app/logout` url.

```
<security:logout logout-url="/app/logout" .... />
```